# Unable to start node.js application written with graphql

Tags: node.js

I have an application written in node.js with graphql, it is running on ubuntu sever, however, i cloned the code onto my local windows 10, installed all packages, and node environment, but when I try to start the app with "node index.js" I got the following error.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer.                 Received type object
at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:263:10)
at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:297:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:/MyProjects/appletree/apple-tree-backend/configs/constants.js:5:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at loader (D:\MyProjects\appletree\apple-tree-backend\node_modules\babel-    register\lib\node.js:144:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\MyProjects\appletree\apple-    tree-backend\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:107:12)
at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:266:5)
at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:297:21)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Consider reading [How to ask a good question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the future.

Comment: Regarding your error snippet, it is impossible to say what is exactly wrong with the code without looking at it, but the error you are getting is pretty explicit: “The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer”. Why don’t you start checking that?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I figured out the issue later as I looked into the code, the project used dotenv package which requires a .env file and this file is not included in the source code that's why I couldn't start the code on my local. 
I got the .env file from the production server and now the code can run on my local , thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering, I figured out the issue later as I looked into the code, the project used dotenv package which requires a .env file and this file is not included in the source code that's why I couldn't start the code on my local. I got the .env file from the production server and now the code can run on my local , thanks everyone.